# Using stripe, is it possible to get all of the data from the Payment Method object using "result.setupIntent.payment_method"?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Right above the links destination: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session
You still see `"When the SetupIntent succeeds, the resulting PaymentMethod ID (in result.setupIntent.payment_method) will be saved to the provided Customer."`
Is it possible to extract all of the information from the payment_method object? Such as expiration date, last 4 digits, type of card etc...? I am only able to get the ID just using the quoted result phrase. I looked for info on their API docs but it doesnt seem like it is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve to get the details of the Payment Method server-side.